# Make parsha tags consistent

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, transliteration

I know questions about consistency in the tags have already been raised, but I wish to raise the question about one particular set of tags - the parsha tags.

The main problems in this area are:

a) Some parshas have the word "parshat/parshas" attached to them and some don't.
b) No consistency in the Ashkenazi/Sefardic pronunciations.
c) The transliteration is very poor in many of the tags.

If will you ask what the big deal is, apart from being untidy and apart from making tag searching harder, it looks very amateurish, and this site should aim at looking professional as much as possible. Would you allow your own websites to appear like this?

As to the argument that it would be too much work, I would be happy to undertake the work myself, but I don't know if I have enough points to do so.

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/679/759

Comment: Why no "a" in Parashat? Consider [Esther 4:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3304.htm#7) or [Esther 10:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3310.htm#2).

Comment: What about lack of consistency to Temani pronunciations?

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at previous Meta questions on [meta-tag:transliteration], see what was discussed there, and consider contributing to those discussions.

Comment: What's the problem with having four or five tags for the same parshah all mapped to each other using various transliterations and spellings?

Comment: @DonielFilreis Nothing. The problem is that not all of them have the synonyms.

Comment: so it's been 6 years! What permissions needed to edit tags?